# spawn_monitor registered name in different module

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to monitor a process with a registered name in a different module than where the monitor code is placed. This is an assignment for school, which is why I'm not going to post all of my code. However, here's the outline:

`module1:start()` spawns a process and registers its name:

```
register(name, Pid = spawn(?MODULE, loop, [])), Pid.
```

The loop waits for messages. If the message is of the wrong type it crashes.

`module2:start()` should start the registered process in `module1` and monitor it, restarting it if it's crashed. I've been able to get it working using:

```
spawn(?MODULE, loop, [module1:start()]).
```

Then in the loop function I use `erlang:monitor(process, Pid)`.

This way of solving the problem means the registered process can crash before the monitoring starts. I've been looking at `spawn_monitor`, but haven't been able to get the monitoring to work. The latest I've tried is:

```
spawn(?MODULE, loop, [spawn_monitor(name, start, [])]).
```

It starts the registered process. I can send messages to it, but I can't seem to detect anything. In the loop function I have a `receive` block, where I try to pattern match `{'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, _Why}`. I've tried using `spawn_monitor` in `module1` instead of simply `spawn`, but I noticed no change. I've also been trying to solve this using links (as in `spawn_link`), but I haven't gotten that to work either.

Any suggestions? What am I monitoring, if I'm not monitoring the registered process?

Comment: Should module2 start only if module1 has started?

Comment: Hmm.. no, module2 should start before module1. Module2 should be the one that starts module1 (i.e. calls it's start() function, which registers a name), and then restarts it if the Pid registered to a name in module1 crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a homework assignment, I won't give you a complete answer.

Generally, you need two loops, one in `module1` to do the work, and one in `module2` to supervise the work. You already have a `module1:start/0` function that calls `spawn` to execute the `module1:loop/0` function to do the work, but as you've stated, this leaves a window of vulnerability between the spawning of the process and its monitoring by `module2` that you're trying to close. As a hint, you could change the `start` function to call `spawn_monitor` instead:

```
start() ->
    {Pid, Ref} = spawn_monitor(?MODULE, loop, []),
    register(name, Pid),
    {Pid, Ref}.
```

and then your `module2:start/0` function would then just call it like this:

```
start() ->
    {Pid, Ref} = module1:start(),
    receive
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Pid, _Why} ->
            %% restart the module1 pid
            %% details left out intentionally
    end.
```

Note that this implies that `module2:start/0` needs a loop of some sort to spawn and monitor the `module1` pid, and restart it when necessary. I leave that to your homework efforts.

Also, using `spawn_link` instead of `spawn_monitor` is definitely worth exploring.

Comment: This is actually what I tried before I posted, a number of times, without realizing it really was the right way to go at it. I couldn't get it to work, and couldn't see why it wouldn't work. My conclusion was that I had missed something crucial. It turned out to be a different problem. I was `exit`-ing the wrong process (due to a call to a different function), which was why my monitor didn't receive the message. I'll mark this, because it made me realize something else had to be wrong.